# How to copy images from multiple sub-folders to a common folder and rename them?

Tags: python, image, directory, copy, rename

Lets assume the following source and destination paths:

```
dir_src = r"/path/to/folder_with_subfolders"
dir_dst = r"/path/to/destination_folder"
```

The directory "folder_with_subfolders" contains multiple sub-folders and their associated files as shown in the tree diagram below:

```
├── folder_with_subfolders
│   ├── Subfolder_1
|   |   ├── Subfolder1_1
|   |   |   ├──Subfolder_with_patientID1
|   |   |   |   ├── 1.dcm
|   |   |   |   ├── 2.dcm
|   |   |   |   ├── 3.dcm
                    .......
│   ├── Subfolder_2
|   |   ├── Subfolder2_1
|   |   |   ├──Subfolder_with_patientID2
|   |   |   |   ├── 1.dcm
|   |   |   |   ├── 2.dcm
                    .......
│   ├── Subfolder_3
|   |   ├── Subfolder3_1
|   |   |   ├──Subfolder_with_patientID3
|   |   |   |   ├── 1.dcm
|   |   |   |   ├── 2.dcm
|   |   |   |   ├── 3.dcm
|   |   |   |   ├── 4.dcm
                    .......
```

It can be seen that the DICOM image files have the same names (1.dcm, 2.dcm, 3.dcm, ...) but they belong to different patients. The sub-folders "Subfolder_with_patientID1", "Subfolder_with_patientID2", "Subfolder_with_patientID3" have different folder names specific to that patient. I want to copy all these DICOM images to the destination directory while renaming them such that each image name is appended with that patient-specific subfolder name, i.e., like the name of the Subfolder_with_patientID1_1.dcm, the name of the Subfolder_with_patientID1_2.dcm and so on. This is the starting script:

```
import glob
import os

# Location with subdirectories
dir_src = r"/path/to/folder_with_subfolders/"
#destination loction to move all the files
dir_dst = r"/path/to/destination/"    
# Get List of all images
files = glob.glob(dir_src + '/**/**/**/*.dcm', recursive=True)     
for file in files:
    # Get File name and extension
    filename = os.path.basename(file)
    filename=filename[:-4].replace(".",.........) + ".dcm"
    # Copy the file with os.rename
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(dir_dst, filename)):
        os.rename(file, os.path.join(dir_dst, filename))
```

Comment: What is preventing you from renaming them?

Comment: Do you intend to move or just copy the files?

Comment: I just want to copy the files but each filename should be appended with its patient-specific subfolder name. For instance, each patient-specific subfolder name is something like this: "4470-Heart", "4472-Heart", "4476-Heart", and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [shutil.copy2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2) to copy the files.

```
import glob
import os
import shutil

# Location with subdirectories
dir_src = "/home/nponcian/Documents/folder_with_subfolders/"

# Destination location to copy all the files
dir_dst = "/home/nponcian/Documents/folder_with_subfolders_dest/"

# Get List of all images
files = glob.glob(dir_src + '/**/*.dcm', recursive=True)

# Create the destination directory
if not os.path.exists(dir_dst):
    os.mkdir(dir_dst)

# For each image
for file_name_src in files:
    # Let's say file_name_src is currently "/home/nponcian/Documents/folder_with_subfolders/Subfolder_1/Subfolder1_1/Subfolder_with_patientID1/2.dcm"

    file_dir = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(file_name_src))  # Would be "Subfolder_with_patientID1"
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_name_src)  # Would be "2.dcm"

    file_name_dst = os.path.join(dir_dst, f"{file_dir}_{file_name}")  # Would be "/home/nponcian/Documents/folder_with_subfolders_dest/Subfolder_with_patientID1_2.dcm"

    shutil.copy2(file_name_src, file_name_dst)
    print(f"Copied:\n\tFr: {file_name_src}\n\tTo: {file_name_dst}")
```

File tree before the script was run

```
$ tree
.
├── folder_with_subfolders
│   ├── Subfolder_1
│   │   └── Subfolder1_1
│   │       └── Subfolder_with_patientID1
│   │           ├── 1.dcm
│   │           ├── 2.dcm
│   │           └── 3.dcm
│   ├── Subfolder_2
│   │   └── Subfolder2_1
│   │       └── Subfolder_with_patientID2
│   │           ├── 1.dcm
│   │           └── 2.dcm
│   └── Subfolder_3
│       └── Subfolder3_1
│           └── Subfolder_with_patientID3
│               ├── 1.dcm
│               ├── 2.dcm
│               ├── 3.dcm
│               └── 4.dcm
└── script.py

10 directories, 10 files
```

File tree after the script was run

```
$ tree
.
├── folder_with_subfolders
│   ├── Subfolder_1
│   │   └── Subfolder1_1
│   │       └── Subfolder_with_patientID1
│   │           ├── 1.dcm
│   │           ├── 2.dcm
│   │           └── 3.dcm
│   ├── Subfolder_2
│   │   └── Subfolder2_1
│   │       └── Subfolder_with_patientID2
│   │           ├── 1.dcm
│   │           └── 2.dcm
│   └── Subfolder_3
│       └── Subfolder3_1
│           └── Subfolder_with_patientID3
│               ├── 1.dcm
│               ├── 2.dcm
│               ├── 3.dcm
│               └── 4.dcm
├── folder_with_subfolders_dest
│   ├── Subfolder_with_patientID1_1.dcm
│   ├── Subfolder_with_patientID1_2.dcm
│   ├── Subfolder_with_patientID1_3.dcm
│   ├── Subfolder_with_patientID2_1.dcm
│   ├── Subfolder_with_patientID2_2.dcm
│   ├── Subfolder_with_patientID3_1.dcm
│   ├── Subfolder_with_patientID3_2.dcm
│   ├── Subfolder_with_patientID3_3.dcm
│   └── Subfolder_with_patientID3_4.dcm
└── script.py

11 directories, 19 files
```

Logs

```
$ python3 script.py 
Copied:
    Fr: /home/nponcian/Documents/folder_with_subfolders/Subfolder_2/Subfolder2_1/Subfolder_with_patientID2/2.dcm
    To: /home/nponcian/Documents/folder_with_subfolders_dest/Subfolder_with_patientID2_2.dcm
Copied:
    Fr: /home/nponcian/Documents/folder_with_subfolders/Subfolder_2/Subfolder2_1/Subfolder_with_patientID2/1.dcm
    To: /home/nponcian/Documents/folder_with_subfolders_dest/Subfolder_with_patientID2_1.dcm
Copied:
    Fr: /home/nponcian/Documents/folder_with_subfolders/Subfolder_1/Subfolder1_1/Subfolder_with_patientID1/3.dcm
    To: /home/nponcian/Documents/folder_with_subfolders_dest/Subfolder_with_patientID1_3.dcm
Copied:
    Fr: /home/nponcian/Documents/folder_with_subfolders/Subfolder_1/Subfolder1_1/Subfolder_with_patientID1/2.dcm
    To: /home/nponcian/Documents/folder_with_subfolders_dest/Subfolder_with_patientID1_2.dcm
Copied:
    Fr: /home/nponcian/Documents/folder_with_subfolders/Subfolder_1/Subfolder1_1/Subfolder_with_patientID1/1.dcm
    To: /home/nponcian/Documents/folder_with_subfolders_dest/Subfolder_with_patientID1_1.dcm
Copied:
    Fr: /home/nponcian/Documents/folder_with_subfolders/Subfolder_3/Subfolder3_1/Subfolder_with_patientID3/3.dcm
    To: /home/nponcian/Documents/folder_with_subfolders_dest/Subfolder_with_patientID3_3.dcm
Copied:
    Fr: /home/nponcian/Documents/folder_with_subfolders/Subfolder_3/Subfolder3_1/Subfolder_with_patientID3/4.dcm
    To: /home/nponcian/Documents/folder_with_subfolders_dest/Subfolder_with_patientID3_4.dcm
Copied:
    Fr: /home/nponcian/Documents/folder_with_subfolders/Subfolder_3/Subfolder3_1/Subfolder_with_patientID3/2.dcm
    To: /home/nponcian/Documents/folder_with_subfolders_dest/Subfolder_with_patientID3_2.dcm
Copied:
    Fr: /home/nponcian/Documents/folder_with_subfolders/Subfolder_3/Subfolder3_1/Subfolder_with_patientID3/1.dcm
    To: /home/nponcian/Documents/folder_with_subfolders_dest/Subfolder_with_patientID3_1.dcm
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to split out the subfolder:

```
subfolder = os.path.dirname(file).split('/')[-1]
```

Then add the subfolder into your rename:

```
os.rename(file, dir_dst + subfolder + '_' + filename)
```

So the section should look something like this:

```
import glob
import os

# Location with subdirectories
dir_src = r"/path/to/folder_with_subfolders/"
#destination loction to move all the files
dir_dst = r"/path/to/destination/"    
# Get List of all images
files = glob.glob(dir_src + '/**/**/**/*.dcm', recursive=True)     
for file in files:
    # Get File name and extension
    filename = os.path.basename(file)
    subfolder = os.path.dirname(file).split('/')[-1]
    # Copy the file with os.rename
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(dir_dst, filename)):
         os.rename(file, dir_dst + subfolder + '_' + filename)
```

Comment: How to get the name of the patient-specific sub-folder inside the FOR loop? This patient-specific subfolder name changes for its dedicated sub-folder. Could you please mind posting the entire script adding these lines? Thanks.

Comment: For instance, each patient-specific subfolder name is something like this: "4470-Heart", "4472-Heart", "4476-Heart", and so on.

Comment: Hey, just written it out now, I was unsure of what you were trying to achieve with:
`filename=filename[:-4].replace(".",.........) + ".dcm"`

Comment: os.rename will move and rename though. if you need to copy you need to use shutil (copy2 to preserve metadata)